# With AWS Elastic Beanstalk where should I store my application code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As I containerized my app my plan was to build my docker image with my application files inside the image, and then update my image when my code changed.

Now that I am digging into AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB) though it seems that maybe I should just zip my whole application up with each deploy, and then remove my application code from my image.

Would it even work with storing my application code on the docker image with AWS EB? If so, which would be best to use?

If I decided to switch to AWS ECS (or another service) later on would it be best to just store my application code on my docker image?

Edit: I should note that I'm using a multi-container Docker

Comment: git ?  AWS CodeCommit / GitLab / GitHub / BitBuckets are all valid options

Answer (score 0):

With AWS Elastic Beanstalk consider storing your application code on Amazon S3.